# How could I launch the sequence of git commands from java application?

Tags: java, git

I need to add the file to the repository and then commit it from my java project. I use

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin\\sh.exe");
```

to start git but what should I do next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of running the command line tool directly from your Java application, consider using Git APIs for Java, such as JavaGit. The [cookbook](http://javagit.sourceforge.net/cookbook.php) has examples that you can follow.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I try to solve the problem with "020100: Unable to start sub-process." Could you give me advice why could this occur?

Comment: I had to add git path to system environment. I got it. Problem has solved. Thx

Answer (score 3):

I code should be something like this:

```
public void gitCommands() throws IOException {

   // Build command 
   List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
   commands.add("/bin/bash");
   commands.add("-c");
   commands.add("git add .");       

   StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();

   ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
   pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
   process process = pb.start();


   //EDIT:
   // get Exit Status   
   process.waitFor();


   //go for next commands
   .....

}
```

Comment: Better to wait for the process to finish instead of sleeping for an arbitrary duration. Also, beware of typos in this example. It won't work out of the box.

Comment: thanks, I guess it is better use process.waitFor(), isn't it ?

Comment: Yes. There are very few legitimate uses of sleep().

Answer (score 2):

sh.exe isn't Git, it's the command shell distributed with Git. You'd want to run Git directly, e.g. like this:

```
String[] command = {"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin\\git.exe",
                    "add",
                    "some-file-to-add"};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

But since you're writing in Java I suggest you have a look at [JGit](http://www.eclipse.org/jgit/), a native Java Git library.